# Java Serialization issues on Restlet versions above 2.1-M4

Tags: java, android, serialization, restlet

I'm trying to run the very simple Restlet sample app available here http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.2/introduction/first-steps/first-application

I'm trying to run the client on an Android device, but I get the following error:

```
Unable to convert a [application/json,UTF-8] representation into an object of class org.restlet.example.common.Contact
java.io.IOException: Unable to create the Object representation
org.restlet.engine.converter.DefaultConverter.toObject(DefaultConverter.java:291)
org.restlet.service.ConverterService.toObject(ConverterService.java:170)
org.restlet.resource.Resource.toObject(Resource.java:828)
org.restlet.engine.resource.ClientInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInvocationHandler.java:240)
$Proxy7.retrieve(Native Method)
org.restlet.example.serialisation.android.activity.ContactActivity$2.run(ContactActivity.java:142)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The serialized representation must have this media type: application/x-java-serialized-object or this one: application/x-java-serialized-object+xml
org.restlet.representation.ObjectRepresentation.<init>(ObjectRepresentation.java:204)
org.restlet.representation.ObjectRepresentation.<init>(ObjectRepresentation.java:133)
org.restlet.representation.ObjectRepresentation.<init>(ObjectRepresentation.java:114)
org.restlet.engine.converter.DefaultConverter.toObject(DefaultConverter.java:288)
```

The only way to make this app working is to use the Restlet 2.1-M4 version. I tried with 2.2-RC2 and even with the "stable" 2.1.7 Restlet release.

I understand the app has been tested with "Restlet Framework 2.1 Milestone 4", but it sounds too weird to me that a later stable release such the 2.1.7 goes nuts on a trivial example like this one!

The app itself is so simple that I cannot see where the problem might ever rely, except for a "bug" of the restlet library itself.
The only other option I can imagine is that after restlet 2.1-m4, in order to have java serialization working fine, there must be some additional piece of code to add in the client and/or the server that was not necessary with 2.1-m4.

Any comments or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Best,

Raffaele Gravina

Answer (score -1):

Due to potential security issues, we had to disable default converters as explained here:
https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/wiki/XEE-security-enhancements

YOu should add the Jackson extension to your classpath (org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar and dependencies). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Jerome, so all I need to do is to add org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar in my classpath? Should I also have to explicitly set the Jackson converter in my java source?

Also, cloud you kindly be more precise: which libraries are known to be required by org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar ?
Thanks for your support!

Comment: Jerome Louvel, can you please elaborate your answer. I am also facing this problem. By adding jackson jars nothing helped. Should I modify java code in order to force use jackson?

Comment: If you configure the Jackson extension via Maven, all the dependencies come automatically. If you use the Zip distribution, there is a /lib/readme.txt file that list all the dependencies.

Comment: I have the same problem with a J2SE Client and Restlet Version 3.0-M1. 
As suggested i've added org.restlet.ext.jackson (Maven) but this doesn't help... 

How do i het my client up and running now? I'm trying to POST serialised objects via JSON to my GAE server.